# saving object to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have a ruby on rails 4 app and I'm using `omniauth-facebook` gem for authentication. I have

```
@omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
```

Now I'd like to save a user's education history (`@omniauth[:extra][:raw_info][:education]`) in the `education` column of `Auth` table in the database. `@omniauth[:extra][:raw_info][:education]` is an Array object which contains `OmniAuth::AuthHash` objects (i.e. `@omniauth[:extra][:raw_info][:education][0].class` returns `OmniAuth::AuthHash`).

Rails api says that "Active Record can serialize any object in text columns using YAML. To do so, you must specify this with a call to the class method serialize. This makes it possible to store arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects without doing any additional work." So I did the following and it seems to be working:

```
auth.education = @omniauth[:extra][:raw_info][:education]
auth.save
```

Is there any downside to this? Is there a better way (like using json, etc)? One downside I can think is that saving data this way makes it difficult for search and query which I probably won't be needing.

Thanks a lot.